# CSharpCodeProvider fails to compile function but Visual studio compiles the same function

Tags: c#-3.0

Here's a simple function. Compiling this code using the CSharpCodeProvider fails but it works when I attempt to reproduce the problem using Visual studion. The error I get is "unable to implicitly convert uint? to uint". Any ideas ?

public static Boolean Func1()
        {
            UInt32? x = 0;
            UInt32? y = 0;
            return x == (UInt32?)0;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VS are you using? I guess VS 2008.

Have you tried to force the compiler version to be used? IIRIC, by default C# 2.0 will be used (even in a C# 3.0 app).

For more information see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397730.aspx).